# What is the mountain lake in this photo?

Tags: identify-this

I found this picture in a garbage bin, and felt like wanting to go there, but I have no idea how to.

Does it ring a bell to anyone?

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151884/discussion-on-question-by-cyrille-corpet-what-is-the-mountain-lake-in-this-photo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like Ventisquero Negro in Argentina.

It’s about a 2-hour drive on one-way gravel roads from the national park entrance outside of San Carlos de Bariloche. If you're ever in Argentina, it's well worth the visit!

[image: Ventisquero Negro Satellite]

[image: Ventisquero Negro View]

Comment: I'll always be amazed by how there is always someone who recognises the location!

Answer (score 19):

I don't know which actual lake that is in your photo.

However, what your photo shows is a "terminal lake" at the end of a glacier. The glacier is the rough looking dark tongue that extends from the top left of the photo into the upper left part of the lake. Glaciers are made of ice, but they are often covered in dirt and rocks so they look dark. The water for the lake comes from the melting ice.

The characteristic light blue colour is caused by the large amount of silt in the water, in combination with the way the sunlight reflects off the lake.

Here is another terminal lake, [Tasman Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasman_Lake) in the south island of New Zealand. The glacier in this photo is at the bottom, and the water flows into the background to another lake ([Lake Pukaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Pukaki)). Tasman Lake is easy to visit, you can drive almost up to the edge of the lake. You can even take a boat ride on the lake.

[image: Tasman Lake]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the terminology "terminal lake"! (although I had kind of deduced from the picture that it was a glacier lake). If I ever go to NZ, I'll definitely take a look at Tasman lake

Comment: *Tasman Lake is easy to visit* — except that it's in a remote part of one of the most remote countries in the world for a very large part of the world population :D

Comment: @gerrit: Okay, yes, that is indeed a matter of perspective. On the other hand, I could be there this afternoon! :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]I'm pretty sure this is the Triftsee in Switzerland.  I traveled there a couple years ago to cross the Trift Bridge and it looks very similar.  I'll link a few other sites that show older photos before the glacier melted.  I'm thinking the little "islands" in the middle of the lake in your photo are the last bits of the glacier sticking out of the water.

https://www.swisseduc.ch/glaciers/big_melt/index-en.html?id=10

Notice the river on the left side of the unmelted photo is in a similar location and shape as your aerial photo.  My guess is your photo was taken sometime around 2003-2004 when the bridge was being built.

https://www.alpenwild.com/staticpage/suspension-bridges-in-switzerland/

That link has more information about the bridge history.

Comment: I really have a hard time reconciling surrounding features (not the lake itself of course as its level and thus shape could have varied a lot over time) between Google Maps satellite imagery of Triftsee and OP’s picture.

Comment: It doesn't look similar to me https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiQtj.jpg the forest at the bottom of the picture is missing

Comment: The little "islands" are pieces of ice floating in the water after having fallen off the face of the glacier.

Answer (score 2):

The same as Greg's answer, I can share some examples of terminal lakes in Kazakhstan. I hope it gives you something :)

Big Almaty lake
[image: BAO]

Kayindy
[image: Kayindy]

Kol'say
[image: Kol'say]

Comment: To say the least, it gives me great pictures, thanks!